# Search functionality Organizational Chart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx-webparts, organization-chart

Is there any Organizational Chart web part sample for SharePoint Online that has the search functionality which allows any user to search by employee name?

I found that Pulmsail already has this functionality:

https://plumsail.com/sharepoint-orgchart/

Do we have any other alternative provided by the community as a sample?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out Joao Mendes' sample web part: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-organization-chart

It should get you started.

I hope this helps?